# ¿Como saco una cuenta de correo que tenga cualquier numero, letra o caracteres especiales?

Tags: r, string

Para encontrar cuentas con cualquier número de letras he usado el código que se muestra, pero de esta forma no puedo sacar cuentas que tengan **números** y **caracteres especiales**.

```
email <- str_extract_all(mail, "[a-z]+\\\\\@[a-z]+\\\\.[a-z]+")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes filtrar tambien con `str_extract()` del mismo package **stringr**

```
   #R version 3.3.2 
library(stringr)
a <- c('patricio.vega12345@gmail.com','tuejemplo999@gmail.com','email@outlook.es','stack_overflow_es@email.com')
b <- str_extract(a, '\\S+@\\S+|\\{(?:\\w+, *)+\\w+\\}@[\\w.-]+')
b
```

Respuesta

```
[1] "patricio.vega12345@gmail.com" "tuejemplo999@gmail.com"      
[3] "email@outlook.es"             "stack_overflow_es@email.com"
```

El ejemplo usando `str_extract_all()`

```
#R version 3.3.2 
library(stringr)
a <- c('patricio.vega12345@gmail.com','tuejemplo999@gmail.com','email@outlook.es','stack_overflow_es@email.com')
b <- str_extract_all(a, '\\S+@\\S+|\\{(?:\\w+, *)+\\w+\\}@[\\w.-]+')
b
```

imprime lo siguiente

```
[[1]]
[1] "patricio.vega12345@gmail.com"

[[2]]
[1] "tuejemplo999@gmail.com"

[[3]]
[1] "email@outlook.es"

[[4]]
[1] "stack_overflow_es@email.com"
```

Comment: Y si tengo varias paginas llenas de cuentas de correo? Cuando uso str_extract_all y cuando str_extract? Corrígeme si me equivoco, pero por lo que se el primero es para una búsqueda mas amplia, y el segundo para una búsqueda mas exacta. Si quiero hacer una lista con todos los correos de tres paginas distintas, no tendria que usar str_extrac_all? Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: hola @Gel , estas en lo correcto, pero como la pregunta no especificaste tanto expuse el ejemplo apegado a tu problematica,  agregue el mismo ejemplo pero con str_extract_all